# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (3)

Tags: недопустимая-метка, терминология

В последнее время часто в вопросах стали упоминаться свойства русского языка. Очень хочется поучаствовать в дискуссиях, но не позволяет ограниченность образования.

Уважаемые форумчане, пожалуйста, объясните дилетанту, что такое свойства русского языка?

Comment: Я думаю, это должен ответить тот, кто употребляет это сочетание. 

Понимать его можно по-разному. Поэтому я удалила первый ответ.

Comment: Как я понял, автор вопросов под этим словосочетанием имеет в виду принципы русской орфографии (использование на письме беззвуковых знаков, букв с дополнительными свойствами в зависимости от позиции и пр.).

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы уважаемые форумчане объяснили дилетанту, что такое свойства русского языка.

Comment: >Я не возражаю, чтобы "уважаемые форумчане" объяснили "дилетанту", что такое свойства русского языка.  
  
Тайна сия велика есть.

Answer (score 3):

Свойства- все качества, признаки, составляющие особенность языка и отличающие его от другого языка. Они бывают структурные и коммуникативные.

Вот, например:1) событийность - способность представлять описываемую ситуацию в виде события, в виде разворачивающегося действия;
2) предсказательность - взаимосвязанные явления одного порядка;
3) принцип «не экономить на материале» - способность сводится к тому, что материальная сторона знаковых единиц русского языка чутко реагирует на изменения содержательной стороны знака,  т.е. изменяется значение идеальной стороны знака.
Эти свойства проявляются на всех уровнях - фонетическом, морфемном и морфологическом, лексическом, синтаксическом.

Качества речи - это тоже свойства: богатство, простота, изящество, певучесть и т.д.

Так что все качества, все признаки языка мы можем назвать свойствами

Comment: >Так что все качества, все признаки языка мы можем назвать свойствами  

Не хочу возражать по сути, но вот система понятий вызывает у меня чувство дискомфорта.   

Разве качества, признаки и свойства это не три(!) "большие разницы"? ну качества и свойства я еще могу как-то отождествить... Но признаки?

Comment: Не думаю: значение слова Свойство по Ожегову:
Свойство - качество, признак, составляющий отличительную особенность кого-чего-нибудь
Значение слова Свойство по Ефремовой:
Свойство - отличительная особенность, черта, характерный признак кого-л., чего-л.
Свойство в Энциклопедическом словаре:
Свойство - философская категория, выражающая отношение данной вещи к др.вещам, с которыми она вступает во взаимодействие. Свойство нередко рассматривается как внешнее выражение качества. 
 http://tolkslovar.ru/s2742.html

Comment: Да. "Признаки русского языка". Каковы они? Если мы, например, слышим большое количество матов - это, по-моему явный _признак_ русского языка.

Comment: Принял к сведению, что "если Вы, например, слышите большое количество матов - это, по-вашему явный *признак* русского языка".

Comment: >значение слова Свойство по Ожегову...   
  
Вы для терминологию черпаете из общеязыковых толковых словарей?!
Да оно бы и полбеды... Но как тогда вся систематика выглядит? 
Свойства,признаки и качества - синонимы? В чем тогда смысл заявления "все признаки есть свойства"?  
Я-то по простоте душевной всегда полагал, что свойства это то, что объединяет объекты, а признаки то, что их отделяет от подобных...  
Но готов снять в пользу любого разумного определения.
Интересно потому, что вежде приводят некие "свойства языка" (в т.ч. вщаимоисключающие), но нигде нет самого понятия "свойство".

Comment: Термин "свойство языка" не противоречит понятию "свойство" - то, что свойственно.В языкознании я назвала основные свойства р. яз. Вот поискала, нашла использование этих сведений в диссертации на кандидатскую степень: http://www.referun.com/n/napisanie-tsi-i-tsy-v-sisteme-russkoy-orfografii-i-idiostile-pisateley-v-svete-determinantnyh-svoystv-russkogo-yazyka#ixzz2fSVJrqit "Проанализировать написание «ЦИ» и «ЦЫ» в отношении к детерминантным свойствам языка - событийности, предсказательности, избыточности («не экономить на языковом материале»), «положению на шкале лексичности / грамматичности».

Comment: Детерминантные свойства-типологические. Так что я правильно понимаю, что такое свойства языка, это научно.

Answer (score 1):

Свойствами русского языка могут являться те критерии, по которым идет классификация языков. Например, **флективность** и **номинативность**.

Comment: Это свойство грамматики, а не языка как такового.

Comment: Свойства грамматики языка есть свойства и языка как такового, ибо грамматика языка есть составляющая языка.

Comment: На заметку модераторам (реплика после чтения последнего комментария). От господина болотного сатаниста бегемотуса прет такой густой запашище, что давно пора **выносить всех святых** с форума))))))) Примите же наконец меры против активного пропагандона-эпигона сатанизма и пошлой демагогии.

Comment: @Дерзкий, что же вы кнопку Тревога не жмёте? А, вы просто уже догадались, какой интернет-мем использует модератор.

**Всем пофиг**

Comment: >>Вы как якобы математику должно быть известно, что свойства системы не складываются из свойств её элементов.

 Эмерджентность не отменяет того, что свойства системы складываются из свойств элементов и свойств их взаимосвязи.

Comment: >@Дерзкий , что же вы кнопку Тревога не жмёте?  
Ты че, клонус-стопкранус-бегемотус, совсем рехнулся?)) Кнопка Тревога относится к вопросу, а не к комментам. Жми сам, куда хочешь, хоть в богадельню...

Comment: >Эмерджентность не отменяет того, что свойства системы складываются из свойств элементов и свойств их взаимосвязи.  
  
Эмержентность может и оно не отменяет. Но уж Ваш ответ насчет свойств языка, наследуемых от грамматики - отменяет точно. 
Так что - не извольте беспокоиться.

Answer (score 1):

Сделав над собой некоторое усилие и заставив себя отнестись к теме серьезно, обнаружил полную вакханалию в понимании самого понятия "свойства языка".

Пожалуй, мне ближе всего понимание, вытекающее из нижеследующего списка "свойств":

а)все языки являются средством общения между людьми;

б)всякий язык участвует в формировании и выражении мысли;

в)единицы любого языка обладают значением;

г)все языки могут функционировать в устной и письменной форме, последняя возникает на определенном этапе развития коллектива — носителя языка;

д)любой язык способен получить при соответствующих исторических условиях литературное нормирование и стилевое членение.

Отсюда имеем, что "свойства языка" трактуются как наиболее значимые проявления языка в процессе его функционирования. Определение не слишком утилитарно, но я и не претендую. надеюсь, что суть понятна.

Соответственно признаками (характеристическими) русского языка будут специфические для русского языка проявления его функционирования. Что ж тогда можно назвать признаками конкретно русского языка?

Даже не знаю...  Ну кириллический алфавит, допустим... Хотя это тоже не признак языка как такового, в лучшем случае - его составной части.

Короче, вся история все больше напоминает притчу о слоне и четырех слепцах.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос интересен тем, что на него проще ответить интуитивно, с помощью примеров, чем дать точное определение.

"Свойства языка" - это должно быть что-то очень значимое и вместе с тем что-то очень простое, понятное. Сразу напрашивается что-то вроде *способности языка выражать мысли* (писал об этом в другом вопросе). Но это - свойство всех языков.

1. Из *особенных* свойств русского я бы, в первую очередь выделил **сложность**. Он кажется более сложным для изучения и восприятия, чем, например, английский.
2. Второе достаточно очевидной свойство - **мощность** (оно отчасти связано с первым). На русском языке выражено, кажется, мыслей больше (и по глубине, выразительности, и по количеству), чем на любом другом.

Answer (score 1):

По моим наблюдениям, **в настоящее время** русский язык - это **живой** язык, а  древнерусский язык - это **мёртвый** язык. Следовательно, все свойства русского языка ещё не определены до конца, а все свойства древнерусского языка уже определены до конца. Говоря другими словами, русский язык - ещё не завершённый процесс (о нём следовало бы говорить в Present Perfect Continuos Tense), а древнерусский язык - уже завершённый процесс (о нём следовало бы говорить в Past Continuous Tense и/или Past Simple Tense).

Далее, **в настоящее время** русский язык - это международный язык (**язык мирового значения**), а, к примеру, словацкий и словенский языки не являются языками мирового значения.

Далее, **в настоящее время** русский язык - это **государственный** язык (например, на территории Республики Беларусь). Как следствие, на этом языке формулируются разнообразные государственные решения (например, о приведении в исполнение приговоров к "высшей мере наказания").

Comment: Совершенно правильно. "Живой" - свойство современного русского языка. "Международный язык" - тоже свойство русского языка. 

Вы запросто нашли два свойства, там где крутые специалисты спорят-дым-коромыслом о том, что это вообще такое!